# C# Linq to SQL optional columns

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have application what creates a table to the database. When some column is empty then its removed from the table. Now im reading the table with other application whats using Linq to SQL. I have generated classes for the whole table. But now when some columsn are missing i get an error.

Does anybody have a good idea how to get passed this problem, is there maybe a way to generate classes dynamically or something?

Comment: Generating classes dynamically is tricky business, with a lot of overhead. Is it possible to just avoid dropping those columns in the first place? Changing schemas on the fly is generally something to be avoided, and ORM frameworks pretty much assume you're not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CodeProject article which has an example of generating a dynamic class
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DynamicClass.aspx